# Cannot call HTTPS from android to Spring Boot backend on same wifi

Tags: android, spring-boot, ssl, webview

I have the following config :

spring boot app running on my laptop with SSL enabled with this config :

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp

server.address=0.0.0.0
server.port=8080
server.error.path=/error

server.ssl.key-store-type=JKS
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:keystore/abc.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password=password
server.ssl.key-alias=alias

server.ssl.enabled=true
```

the spring boot app is running and i can test it on browser on my laptop with HTTPS.

i have an android app on a real device connected to the same wifi network , this app is using webview to get access to the spring boot app , the webview can't connect to the server and i got an error `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

i wonder what is wrong with my config , i know it's something to do with security in spring boot app.

Comment: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED sounds more like maybe you are using either the wrong port or the wrong ip address in your Android app.

Comment: I am sure using the right address and the right port

Comment: We'd need to see the code from the Android side too, I think.

Comment: You're going to need to get more information.  Is there more detail associated with the error in the app? Is there anything in the log file on the server?  Can you hit the URL on a browser on the device?

Comment: There is no error or log shown on the server side , the broWser on the device got the same error « connection refused », I think it’s all about the ssl handshake or something like that

Comment: Okay just a sanity check, you're not using `0.0.0.0:8080` in the app and browser are you? That address is shorthand for "listen on any interface", not a valid target address.

Comment: I am using the IP address of my laptop not 0.0.0.0

Comment: Could be that the firewall on your laptop is blocking access?

Comment: I have a MacBook and the firewall is disabled

Comment: I went through a spring boot setup, using all the `server.*` configuration items and there were no problems connecting, either locally or remotely from an Android device. What's the output of `lsof -nnP | grep ':8080'` from your Terminal?

Comment: @msbit i have this output :  java      1121 user   65u     IPv6 0x458d3c6457777b37       0t0                 TCP *:8080 (LISTEN)

Comment: That all seems to be correct. To rule out network issues, I'd crack open Wireshark on the laptop while making the request from the phone or another device, and look for packets on 8080 (or any other ports, filtering on the source IP of the device).

Answer (score 0):

After connecting with wifi your phone device and Laptop have a separate IP address.

1. Open CMD and type ipconfig
2. get the IP address of your machine.
3. then call your API with address ad https://192.168.2.23:8080/youApiName